# HTML5 Elements Positioning Semantics

Tags: html, semantics

Is this semantic?

```
<!--LINKS-->
<section role="links">

<!--CATEGORIES-->
<section id="categories">
<h3>Categories</h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Aliquam libero</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Consectetuer adipiscing elit</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Metus aliquam pellentesque</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Suspendisse iaculis mauris</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Urnanet non molestie semper</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Proin gravida orci porttitor</a></li>
</ul>
</section>

<!--BLOGROLL LINKS-->
<section id="links">
<h3>Blogroll</h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Aliquam libero</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Consectetuer adipiscing elit</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Metus aliquam pellentesque</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Suspendisse iaculis mauris</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Urnanet non molestie semper</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Proin gravida orci porttitor</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you should be asking is not "Is this semantic?" but "Does this carry the correct semantics". i.e., Is the meaning of the information correctly conveyed from you to the reader? Ultimately, only you know what meaning you wish to convey, so only you can answer the question.

In this case, for example you've used "lorem ipsum" text. But the actual meaning may depend on what those links actually are.

One general comment. There's no ARIA role `links`. Consider using [the `<nav>` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-nav-element) instead of `<section role="links">`. The nav element maps to the ARIA role `navigation` but it is recommended to use the native element if possible.

You can nest `<nav>` elements, so the other sections *could* be changed as well, but you will need to consider whether the nature of those links justifies it. Otherwise `<section>` is fine for those.

Other than that, it looks appropriate.

Comment: I already used <nav> for main navigation which i think is not appropriate to be used for category and blogrol sections of a website hence i used <section> with what i thought was appropriate attribute to describe an element.

Comment: @purpler - That's fine then. Context is very important in choosing the appropriate element.